# In ASP.NET Core MVC Route "MyWebsite/{id}" not hit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC 1.1 with Visual Studio 2017 RTM. My route configuration is below

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

And my `HomeController/Index` action looks something like below

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id)
```

The `localhost` url hits the `Index` action just fine with id being `null`. But when I type `localhost/5`, it doesn't hit this action, instead it gives 404 error. This is really really frustrating as intuitively I thought that if `localhost` hits Index, then `localhost/5` should hit it as well

Comment: `localhost/5` means it would be trying to find a controller named `5Controller` whch cannot exist (the first segment in your route definition is the controller)

Comment: Then how do I match this route? Define another route?

Comment: If you try `localhost?id=5` does it find the URL?

Comment: Yes, it does, but my requirement is that I have to match localhost/5 to an action, is there a way?

Comment: Controller and action are **not optional**, you can't just leave them out with the default route.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, got it working with code 

    routes.MapRoute(name: "vol", template: "{id}", 
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

Comment: @BrianMains, is this the right way to do this?

Comment: @imgen: Yes, it's just odd way to use it

Comment: @BrianMains, but I cannot find another more elegant way to achieve my goal, do you have any idea?

Comment: @imgen yes you would have to customize the route just to work with the ID; be aware that it may cause you routing problems if you customize other routes later....

Answer (score 1):

**`template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"`** means that when no controller and action is specified (just the base url like **Localhost:XXXX**), go to a controller called **Home** and action named **Index** and the **id** can be optional. If you want to pass a value as Id to Index method in Home controller, you have to ::

1. Change your url to Localhost:XXXX/Home/Index/1
2. Add a route attribute on index method that **`[Route("id?")]`** and you will be able to achieve your desired result. This might disrupt the default routing

Comment: is there a not disrupty way of achieving this? I used code `routes.MapRoute(name: "vol", template: "{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });` to achieve the goal, but I am not sure it is the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tips of @BrianMains and @McKabue, I come up with a solution

```
[Route("{id:int}")]
public IActionResult IdRoute(int id)
{
    ....
}
```

This way it won't disrupt default route